# HTML Value attribute Ignores White space between Passed String

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have an EJS file, where I am fetching the name of the national park from the database and passing it to next page in value attribute of a hidden input element.

My `home.ejs` file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/national-parks.css">


  </head>
  <body>


        <div class="container" id="headContainer">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
              <nav class="nav flex-column">
                <a class="nav-link active text-white" href="/login">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-link active text-white" href="/signup">Sign Up</a>
                <a class="nav-link active text-white" href="/logout">Logout</a>
              </nav>
            </div>

            <div class="col-10" id="heading">
              <h1 class="display-3">National Parks Observer</h1>
              <p class="lead">Site Dedicated to Indian National Parks</p>
             </div>


         </div>
        </div>




        <div class="container" id="postings">

         <%  var r=Math.round(nationalParks.length/3); %>
         <% var x = 1; %>
         <% var elementCount = 3; %>
         <% var constant = 3; %>
         <% var start=0; %>
         <% while(x<=r){ %>
          <div class="row">

           <% for(var k=start;k<elementCount;k++){ %>

            <div class="col-4">
              <div class="card">

               <form method="POST" action="/NationalPark">  
                <img class="card-img-top" src=<%=nationalParks[k].imageurl %> alt="Card image cap">


                <h5 class="card-title" name="parktitle" id="title"><%=nationalParks[k].nationalPark %></h5>
                <% var parkName=nationalParks[k].nationalPark %>
                <Input type="hidden" name="park_name" value=<%= parkName %> />  
                  <Input type="hidden" name="google_url" value=<%=nationalParks[k].googleurl %> />      
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View Page</button>

                </form> 

              </div>
           </div>

           <% } %>
           <%  start=start+constant; %>
           <%   elementCount=Math.min(elementCount+constant,nationalParks.length); %>


          </div>

          <% x++; }  %>










        </div>


        <br>
        <br>
        <br>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="/javascript/national-park.js"></script>     

  </body>
</html>
```

Following lines of code works fine if you pass a value say `Jim`

```
<Input type="hidden" name="park_name" value=<%= nationalParks[k].nationalPark %> />
```

but if it encounters a string let's say `Jim Corbett` it does something like this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="park_name" value="Jim" corbett>
```

What's the way to resolve this? Is there any security implication in this? Thanks.

Comment: check the nationalParks Jim Corbett record and see if it contains any special characters. What is different about the Jim Corbett record in the database when compared to the other records?

Comment: Jim Corbett national park name is stored as `Jim Corbett` in db. the other national park names only contain one word string such as `Kaziranga`, `Ranthambhore` etc. Jim Corbett simplay has a space in it.

Comment: Try replacing Jim Corbett in the database with Jim%20Corbett as a test, then rerun the project.

Comment: Tried, did not work, now I am seeing Jim%20Corbett in other places where I am using this value to display as title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Input type="hidden" name="park_name" value='<%= nationalParks[k].nationalPark %>' />
```

instead of this:

```
 <Input type="hidden" name="park_name" value=<%= nationalParks[k].nationalPark %> />
```